# Blueimp carousel displays carousel and images below it

Tags: razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, blueimp

I have implemented the blueimp carousel (2.22.0) on a gallery page. It works fine and is displaying the images in the carousel. But it is also showing all the images below the carousel in a quasi light box style. This is my code.

```
<link href="~/Content/Css/blueimp-gallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="page-header">
    <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
</div>


<!-- The Gallery as inline carousel, can be positioned anywhere on the page -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery-carousel" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-carousel">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
<div id="links">

    @foreach (GalleryViewItemVM item in Model.Images)
    {
        <a href="@item.ImagePath" title="">
            <img src="@item.ThumbPath" alt="">
        </a>
    }
</div>


<script src="~/Scripts/blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    blueimp.Gallery(
        document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a'),
        {
            container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
            carousel: true
        }

    );
</script>
```

For completeness I am using razor and bootstrap 3 although I don't think this relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<img>` tag within the `<a>` tag is unneccesary and is causing the unwanted behavior.